# TableView delegate method called only after a second cell is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm dealing with a problem that is really making me crazy. I've got a table view added to a view using IB. This tableView has a delegate and a datasource. The delegate is the view controller, the data source is another class that packs information for displaying them. The data source works and fill the table with correct data. 
I'm not able to say the same for the delegate. The delegate implements the classic `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and I have an NSLog inside that method that logs the cell selected. 
The problem is that if I selected a cell, the cell changes its color in blue(selected state), but it doesn't trigger the delegate methods. If I press another cell now the new selection on a new cell pushes the detailviewcontroller with the right informations.
If I pop the cell is deseleted- since in viewWillAppear I put a method for deselect selected cell-, if I press a cell again nothing happens just blue selection,if I press another one it pushes the detail view. 
I tried to make few changes to make the case easy as possible:

1. .used default styled cells
2. .added the tableview programmatically
3. .check the delegate of the tableview in different part of the code

Everything seems right I really can't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

instead of

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: SO STUPID, I AM SO STUPID!!!!! Thank you so much!!!! Of course I will accept the answer but I need to wait 5 min

Comment: It's easy to make mistake, coz "DESELECt" goes first